# Visual Studio Java Language Support add jar

Tags: java, visual-studio, import, jar

I'm trying to use Java Language Support tools. So I've created a project and could run it but I also need to reference the external library. So there is a jar file which I tried to add through: References -> Add Reference...

The code is listed below. This way the project can't be built.

```
package pkg;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.BM25Similarity;

public class MySimilarity extends BM25Similarity {
}
```

Any help on adding the library to the project is appreciated.

Answer (score -3):

To add jar use below steps :

right click on project -> build path ->configure build path -> click on add external jar -> select jar from your machine -> click ok

Comment: Is that for eclipse?

Comment: @AOY yes for eclipse

Comment: I need to know how to do this for the java project created in Visual Studio((

Comment: @AOY sry i dont have any idea how to do that in Visual Studio