# Visual Studio Code, Java Extension, how to add a JAR to classpath?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar, executable-jar

In Eclipse IDE, I add a JAR library using

> Project > Build Path > Configure Build Path...

**What is the equivalent in VisualStudioCode?**

I had a look into `launch.json`. There is a classpath defined. Adding JARs to this classpath (array) variable seems to have no effect.

Essentially, this is a duplicate question of
[Visual Studio Java Language Support add jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282178/visual-studio-java-language-support-add-jar).
But that question is unanswered.

This is such an extremely basic question, that I really don't understand not to find a solution for it in Microsoft's documentation or via Google search.

Comment: visual studio code is a text editor its not an ide so your system variables(if you are on windows) will have class path for your java and other libraries

Comment: Start here, I haven't read it completely but you can find useful info https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial

Comment: This is not a duplicate since the question was about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I tried to do: export CLASSPATH=<list of jar files>, then started visual studio code with this environment variable, but the problems stays the same: build fails.

Comment: I am not sure that vscode is really adapted for Java development but anyway this will depend on which extension you will install to develop in Java. What have you installed???  Furthermore, whatever the one you chose, I suggest you to use Maven or Gradle to manage you dependencies.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's correct. Adding jar's to a 'naked'  'hello world' projects seems not to work. So I created a Maven project and added the dependency as`<html> <code><dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency> </code>`</html>` This works.

Comment: So if you added a jar dependency in Eclipse, reopening the same project in vscode should work, if it's a simple Java project.
If it doesn't, please provide a sample project reproducing the issue
here is the sample eclipse project.
i could not import this eclipse project with VS code. I have to use the folder source
[test_vs_code.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iC-GkjLeX8_5wQBzq00_QmEDVM_y2j57)
Works for me (after pointing to a json.jar on my machine). It even works in Atom. Can you try opening this one (the jar is included in the project directory, so it's more portable)?
[test_vs_code2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749388/setting-the-classpath-in-a-visual-studio-code-maven-based-java-project lots of great answers here

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-pack/issues/94

Answer (score 88):

## Update for latest version

Pre-requisite: In VS Code you need to open the folder and not just file to include any jar file for compilation, running, debugging and testing

VSCode works fine with maven or gradle, and if we are using any of those, we should use maven or gradle for dependency management.

If you are not using any dependency management, then there are two options to add jar file

#### Option 1: Manually

Open .vscode/settings.json file (if not present, you can create one) and add required jar file there as shown below. In this case all the jar files present in lib directory will be included + I have added common-logging-1.1.1.jar which is located outside the project directory

```
{
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar",
        "c:\\path\\to\\jarfile\\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"
    ]
}
```

#### Option 2: Via User Interface

If Java Extension is enabled then on left panel there will be Java Dependencies.
Inside there you can click on `+` symbol to add customer jar files. With this method too, the `settings.json` file will be updated

[image: Screenshot for Adding Java Dependency]

## Old Answer kept for reference...

VSCode works fine with maven or gradle. But without those, as far as I know they have not provided any direct way to add jar file in classpath.

The workaround is to add the entry in `.classpath` file manually.

For e.g. in below file I have added `common-logging-1.2.jar` located in `lib` directory manually by adding a line `<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
        <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
        <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

**Update**

Finally VSCode team is working towards a better solution. This is still work in progress, but you can refer to this link for better aproach https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-pack/issues/94#issuecomment-573487982

**Update April 2020**

VSCode Extension update now supports this feature out of the box.
Now VS Code Java lets you work with JAR files directly without any build tools. Go to JAVA DEPENDENCIES view, find the Referenced Libraries node and click the + icon.

Reference https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-pack/blob/master/release-notes/v0.9.0.md#work-with-jar-files-directly

Comment: When I look at Java Dependencies, I don't see a "Referenced Libraries" node.  I just see "JRE System Library".  (I'm running 1.44.2 on macOS 10.15.4)

Comment: I get something similar - all I see is "JRE System Library" node  - to which there is no "+" button, a "Maven Dependencies" node, which does have a "+" button, but then does not allow me to find the dependent jar file on my computer. How do you get the "Referenced Libraries" node to show?

Comment: If you are using maven, you should use maven for dependency management. The above solution is if you are not using maven or gradle

Comment: @Zack I had the same issue, could not find the 'Referenced Libraries' node for a project 
that I had created prior to this update. The solution that worked for me was opening directly (File > Open Folder) the 'src' folder of the project.

Comment: If you are having problems getting the projects menu to appear, double click on a java file (best if its the file with the main method in it). Sometimes the project menu goes away after the workspace is cleared. Also, if you are in Windows, the classpath tools for java for vscode do not like paths with spaces in them. It is best to move those jars to a path with no spaces. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54966653/javafx-11-in-vscode-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-files-java-javafx

Comment: To find "Referenced Libraries", make sure you have installed the extension "Project Manager for Java".

Comment: I posted this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216059/visual-studio-code-vscode-adding-referenced-library-jar-files-using-relative, when using referenced libraries + button it has no effect and it mentioned read only, why? Please help.

Comment: what if there is no + button? what "java dependencies"?

Comment: if there is a .classpath file already in the root of the project, you can not add reference libraries, it's read-only.   Is there a way to tell vscode to use a different .classpath file or to override that behavior  that makes it read-only?

Answer (score 10):

## Follow these steps in `vscode`(2022)

#### Make sure *Extension Pack for Java* is installed

Install [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack), you may need to restart the vscode.

#### Project Structure

Create the **following**

```
.vscode/
 | -- settings.json
bin/
lib/ <-- Add here all the .jar files 
src/ <-- Add here you java source code
```

So that the project structure should look like this

[image]

#### Add settings to `settings.json`

```
{
    "java.project.sourcePaths": [
        "src"
    ],
    "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar",
    ]
}
```

- {
  "java.project.sourcePaths": [
  "src"
  ],
  "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
  "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
  "lib/**/*.jar",
  ]
  }
- **java.project.sourcePaths**: Path of your java source code
- **java.project.outputPath** Binary output
- **java.project.referencedLibraries**: The `.jar` files

Now, restart `vscode` and also if you still have error you many need to **[Clear file content cache in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46102591/13903942)**

Also you should see now the library in the **Referenced Libraries list**. *(Note: this may be updated in future vscode version, like name, position and so on)*

[image]

Comment: I have a multi-module maven project and the source of the secondary module is not available when I debug using a breakpoint. I used `java.project.sourcePaths` but it is ignored. Can you help please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74545754/failed-to-get-sources-when-debugging-multi-module-maven-project-in-vscode

Comment: if there is a .classpath file already in the root of the project, you can not add reference libraries, it's read-only. Is there a way to tell vscode to use a different .classpath file or to override that behavior that makes it read-only?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is pretty old, but it is still high up on Google results and many may find it.
I just want to recommend the following guide to VSCode wich includes a small but sufficient part to including libraries:

https://blog.usejournal.com/visual-studio-code-for-java-the-ultimate-guide-2019-8de7d2b59902

the answer is pretty simple:

1. add the jar to a folder you prefer, e.g. a new directory "lib" in the project folder.
2. add a line like: `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/javaxt-cor.jar"/>`to your  `.classpath`.
3. done. You can simply import it as you are used to.

Comment: I wanted to mention that once you go through the "Create Java project" process in Visual Code, the `.classpath` file appears in your project workspace.

Answer (score 5):

You must have the **Java Dependency Viewer** extension installed which helps import the jar files and add them to the project's classpath ***OR*** add the libraries to the "***.classpath***" file manually by using  `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="manual\path\entry\jarfile.jar"/>` tags within `<classpath></classpath>` tags for each jar file.

First what you want to do is know how to create a proper Java "project" in VS Code.

To do that:

1. Have a folder opened in VSCode
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> to open the **Command Palette**
3. Type in `Java: Create New Project`
4. Follow the steps according to your requirements and provide the project name

Then : Expand the **Java Dependencies** section in your Explorer Panel then Expand your "project name".

1. When you hover over "**Referenced Libraries**" you will see the "**+**" sign. Click it.
2. It will open the explorer. Use it to select all your jar files and click "**Select Jar Files**" button.

That's it!!!!

By the way you can see all of this in detail at
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_working-with-jar-files , it has a clear visual representation of everything related.

Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 3):

import external jar file into java project,now in vscode 1.48.2 is work well,follow the reference below:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_working-with-jar-files

what I want to said is, if your external jar path has Chinese characters，even if put the jar files into lib directory under project root directory and the project path has chinese characters,when you debug or run,it will report an error message like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
```

I had not idea whether this problem  appear in other language characters.be careful.

Answer (score 0):

A terrible solution, but for me it works.
(Assuming maven is installed).

Locate your maven repository directory, for me it is:

`/Users/username/.m2/repository`

Then create the path required following the package name.
If you don't know the package name you can rename the `.jar` to a `.zip` and extract the content.

Also create a version number, if you don't have one then make one up.
Here is a example of a structure that I created for `byte-buddy-agent` since that does not have a maven snippet.

Having done that you edit `pom.xml` and add something among the lines of:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.bytebuddyagent</groupId>
  <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Save the file, reload the changes, and you should be good to go.
A bunch of files should be created in the directory.

[image]

Comment: To add jar file in maven repo, the recommended way is to use `mvn install:install-file`. You may refer to its [document](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html)

Answer (score 0):

For adding external Jar files whithout maven or gradle .classpath file must be changed for the library.. example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-1.2.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

But one extension conflicts with vscode-java. 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=georgewfraser.vscode-javac
.Disable it if you've installed to suppress error if you find after changing .classpath file. You can check this issue-
https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/956

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy, anyway:

1. Create project with java <kbd>ctrl+shift+p</kbd>
2. Add the jar file to your `.classpath`
3. Add on the top of your project package [app]; the name of your package
4. We are done, don't forget to refresh it.

Comment: You leave a HUGE hole between step 1 & 2.  Please revise, add detail

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use the Apache Commons Codec http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/  as an example and start from scratch. I've installed the Visual Studio Code Java Pack Installer https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java and got a new VSCode window.

1. <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> and type to select `Java: Create Java Project`
2. Choose a folder for your project and click `Select the location`
3. Give your project a name and press Enter
4. Create folder in the project called lib and copy in the commons-codec-1.14 folder from the zip file.
5. Open the .classpath file and add the following line inside the  node
    `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/commons-codec-1.14/commons-codec-1.14.jar"/>`
     NB You *may* need to use the absolute address of the lib file. In my first go the above code worked fine. My demo project for this guide only worked with a full path eg 
    `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/tim/Desktop/JavaExample/JavaExample/lib/commons-codec-1.14/commons-codec-1.14.jar"/>`
6. Open the src\App.java file and add the following line below the `package app;` line `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;`

I was then able to run the following code in App.java

```
package app;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String message = "Hello World";
        System.out.println(message);
        String encodedMessage = Base64.encodeBase64String(message.getBytes());
        System.out.println(encodedMessage);

    }
}
```

To produce

```
Hello World
SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read every answer here but none of them seem to  align with the interface I am seeing.  I poked around and noticed that at the bottom of the left hand pane underneath 'OUTLINE' and 'TIMELINE', there was a 'JAVA PROJECTS' accordion menu.  When I hover over it, there's an ellipses which, when clicked, brings up a menu containing the option: 'Configure Classpath'.  Selecting that brings up a Window and the last section is 'Refenced Libraries' where you can add jars from your filesystem.