# Visual Studio Code import Library

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code for Java and I want to debug my code while using a Library. But whenever I start debugging I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    IO cannot be resolved
    IO cannot be resolved
    IO cannot be resolved

    at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:6)
```

for example with the following code:

```
import AlgoTools.IO;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b;
        a = IO.readInt("Please enter a number ");
        b = IO.readInt("Please enter another number ");

        IO.println("Your number is: " + (a + b));
    }
}
```

But when I compile my code in cmd or PowerShell using `javac <Filename>` and running it with `java <Classname>` it works fine. I'm only getting errors when I try to debug in Visual Studio Code.

I should also mention, that I added the path to my .jar Libary in my CLASSPATH.

I'm using the default "Launch" debugging configuration:

```
{
    "type": "java",
    "name": "Debug (Launch)",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "console": "internalConsole",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "mainClass": "",
    "args": ""
},
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the classpath in a Visual Studio Code Maven-based Java project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749388/setting-the-classpath-in-a-visual-studio-code-maven-based-java-project)

Comment: I don't use maven, I don't even know how I should use it. I just want to debug some code for school in VSC. Or do you recommend using maven and when you do, why?

Comment: Ok, I read a little bit about Maven and I should add, that you can't find the Libary in the maven archives (as far as I know), because it's a library from our university.

Comment: I think the answer to that question is applicable even if you don't use Maven.

Answer (score 0):

you should install a extension called "java extension pack" and java maven. or install that offline extension.[click here and get extension name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlYkv.png%60)

Extension URL : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/vscjava/vsextensions/vscode-java-pack/0.4.0/vspackage

Comment: I already installed the java extension pack. and Java Maven is in the expansion pack, so I already installed it but I don't really know how to use Maven.

Comment: go to menu bar and select debug menu and click start without debugging.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Besides that, I want to use the debug features of VSC.