# How to add local jar library to visual studio code?

Tags: java, build, jar, visual-studio-code

I've downloaded some jar files (e.g. `gson-2.8.5.jar`) and want to add them  to **visual studio code locally without any extra downloads** so I can benefit from autocomplete feature of classes and methods, How should I do it?

*I've searched a while in google and could not find anything useful, so even links to other answers is appreciated.*

Comment: Look into this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232557/visual-studio-code-java-extension-howto-add-jar-to-classpath

Comment: @Sambit, I could not figure it out. I tried creating a maven project from archetype and adding the library, but it does not load autocomplete lists.

Comment: How did you add the jar file ? Did you add the dependency for gson in pom.xml ?

Comment: Look into the link which I provided, there is a clear instruction.

Comment: @Sambit, I added it as a classpathentry in .classpath.

Comment: Add the below in dependency section of pom.xml.                           <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Also check this issue. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-pack/issues/94

Comment: @Sambit, thanks, I solved the issue.

Comment: Could you please upvote some my Answers ?

Comment: you could refer to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_standalone-java-file-support)

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT, thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by **LeoZhu-MSFT** which references [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_standalone-java-file-support) in comments all I had to do was open only the folder containing stand-alone *Java* files and if necessary put any jar dependency in a `lib` subdirectory (I was previously opening all directories with code snippets I work on in different languages as playground).