# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' error display while running JMeter load test in VSTS

Tags: jdbc, azure-devops, jmeter, load, load-testing

I am trying to run the **JMeter** load test in VSTS. As this load test runs successfully on my local machine, but displays an error message while using VSTS.
I am using **JDBC Connection Configuration** step to create a connection with SQL server database.

**Error**

```
2019-12-12 11:58:14,882 WARN o.a.j.p.j.p.AbstractJDBCProcessor: SQL Problem in JDBC PostProcessor: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to just simply include the required jar files(in this case jdbc driver jar) along with the other supported files(e.g any csv file for data).
[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This message usually means that the jar file for class `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` was not found in VSTS classpath.

Have a look at this thread which sheds some light on how to achieve this:

[Visual Studio Code, Java Extension, howto add jar to classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232557/visual-studio-code-java-extension-howto-add-jar-to-classpath)