# Adding jar files to VS code?

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code, jar, aiml

I've looked at many questions and answers out there but none seem to answer taking in to consideration the technologies I am using (or understand)

I have created AIML files in eclipse, these have been packaged into jar files using Maven.

Now that I have this jar file (with dependencies all packaged up and in there too) I can't seem to figure out how to add these to VS code so I can add them to the UI I have mocked up?

I (wrongly) thought it would be as simple as creating a "lib" folder within my working folder on VS code and work from there but that doesn't seem to be the case. Can anyone advise on what I should be doing please?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: The answer at the link below seems comprehensive but it doesn't seem to be the answer if I am using maven? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54535301/13686524