# Problems while trying to connect Java with SQL Server Express

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

So, I'm making a simple app where my code connect to a SQL Server Express database. I've all configurated, JDBC, a database, a logon and password. But I keep getting the same error when I try to run the code. The error was that:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=SampleDatabase;user=testLogon;password=sample123
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
        at App.main(App.java:10)
```

I'm currently using VSCode for development, but I have already changed to IntelliJ and Eclipse and I keep getting the same error.

My code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=SampleDatabase;user=testLogon;password=sample123";
        String insertString = "INSERT INTO Pessoa (id, nome, idade) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        try (
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(insertString);
        ) {
            Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa(1, "Maria", 50);

            stmt.setInt(1, p1.getId());
            stmt.setString(2, p1.getNome());
            stmt.setInt(3, p1.getIdade());

            stmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

JDBC jar is already imported

[image]

Comment: you need to add the driver lib to the classpath

Comment: @WSouBar the .jar for the driver is already added

Comment: what is the library that u r using and how have you added this jar in your classpath

Comment: @codeogeek on vscode we can add a external jar file from the "Java Dependencies" tab > Referenced Libraries

Comment: @codeogeek i'm using the default lib that microsoft published for sql server connection: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Since you have mentioned SQL Server express, try this -


String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\sqlexpress;user=sa;password=secret";
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
if (conn != null) {
    System.out.println("Connected");
}

Comment: @codeogeek now I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\sqlexpress;user=testLogon;password=sample123

Comment: Got it.
Try adding the below in your .vscode/settings.json file (if not present, you can create one)

{
    "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
        "lib/**/*.jar",
        "c:\\path\\to\\jarfile\\mssql-jdbc-8.x.x.jre11.jar"
    ]
}

Mention your correct path

Refer the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232557/visual-studio-code-java-extension-howto-add-jar-to-classpath

Comment: @codeogeek keeps getting the same error, my settings: {
  "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
    "lib/**/*.jar",
    "lib/mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre11.jar"
  ]
}

Comment: Can you add the absolute path of the jar

Comment: @codeogeek the error persists, updated settings: {
  "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
    "lib/**/*.jar",
    "C:\\Users\\biewo\\Documents\\Faculdade\\Database\\SQL\\lib\\mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre11.jar"
  ]
}

Comment: Ok
1. try restarting the vsstudio code and try again
Last option which I see right now is running your main class from terminal while giving classpath using flag -cp

Comment: @codeogeek tried, but the error continues. thx for the help but apparently it will be very complicated to fix, I'll leave it for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using Java 8 (Java 8 update 241) to run your program, but are trying to use the version of the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver for Java 11 and higher (as indicated by the `jre11` in the version).

Given the driver is compiled for Java 11, it cannot be loaded by Java 8. Download the Java 8 version of the driver (ending in `jre8`), or upgrade to Java 11.

Comment: damn, that was a simple issue, I changed the absolute path to my openjdk 11 on vscode and everything worked! thanks!