# Use a class from a jar file in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

So, I'm new to Java, and I was looking at how to use a class from a Jar file. I created a java file with all the classes I wanted and then got a Jar file from it, I imported it [using this interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXleF.png) but now how can I actually use it? I'm not using Maven or anything. Just plain java project from VSCode (Java Extension Pack and Jar Builder installed).

I know that maybe I should use a different program but I really like VSCode so If u could help here I would appreciate it :)

Here is the java file that I built the Jar from

```
import java.io.*;
public class Ler {
    public static String umaString (){
        String s = "";
        try{
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader (System.in));
            s= in.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Erro ao ler fluxo de entrada.");
        }
    return s;
    }

    public static int umInt(){
        while(true){
            try{
                return Integer.valueOf(umaString().trim()).intValue();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Não é um inteiro válido!!!");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static char umChar(){
        while(true){
            try{
                return umaString().charAt(0);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Não é um char válido!!!");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static short umShort(){
        while(true){
            try{
                return Short.valueOf(umaString().trim()).shortValue();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Não é um short válido!!!");
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

1.Use the command `javac Ler.java` to compile `Ler.java`;

2.Type the command `jar --create --file Ler.jar Ler.class` to generate `Ler.jar`;

> **Attentio**n: If `Ler.java` is under the subfolder, please enter it then compile and generate .jar.

[image]

3.Add `Ler.jar` to **Referenced Libraries**;

4.Code like `Ler.function`().

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can verify your work with the tips written in the answer to similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54535301/14056755

When you import the library into your plain Java project, you can just summon classes from jar library by using *import* keyword. Your class inside jar library should be placed inside a package.

Example (assuming Ler class is placed inside org.xyz package):

```
import org.xyz.Ler;
```