# How to add referenced library JAR files using relative path for eclipse Java project in vscode

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code, jar, reference-library

I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232557/visual-studio-code-java-extension-howto-add-jar-to-classpath) and many other posts to help me resolve my issue, but nothing worked.

I trying to open an existing Java Project from Eclipse in vscode. The project was opened successfully in Eclipse 2021-06 and I fixed the referenced libraries by selecting the JAR libraries under `lib/` folder and right-click - configure build batch - add select add to build path. Then the file `.classpath` was updated automatically. Then I had to download JDK 11 (needed for vscode) and JDK 1.8 needed for the Java project. I managed to work with eclipse to set the JDK correctly and all worked fine. I was able to compile the project, export the result JAR and deploy and all worked well.

I am having trouble to open this project in vscode using `Open Java Project` option. I am facing issues adding referenced libraries this Java project as it is a managed project (since it was created in Eclipse). When I try to add the libraries using vscode UI, I am getting mixed results and sometimes it is not working and the build fails. I was surprised as in some instances, things just work, and then they don't.

I tried to update `.classpath` file in vscode and still same issues. When I try to add the libraries from `Referenced Libraries (Read Only)` under `JAVA PROJECTS` tree in vscode by clicking `+`, it has no effect. This step will modify the file `settings.json` under `.vscode` folder by adding the relevant values to the property `"java.project.referencedLibraries"`.

I am confused about how to configure the referenced libraries for Java projects in vscode. Following is a summary of questions:

1. How to add a library using a relative path to a Java Project based on the project root folder?
2. What is the difference between adding a library using the `.classpath` file and by modifying `settings.json` file? Which one will win?
3. How to add a folder with all JAR files to be as the referenced library to the Java Project? This is to avoid adding one file at a time.
4. Why the `.classpath` and `.project` files are not showing in vscode explorer view? It will only show when you open the file in vscode from the Windows File Explorer.
5. I found command `Configure Classpath` but it is read-only, which I think it is the same as the `.classpath` file. Is there a way to change it from vscode UI?
6. When I remove `.classpath` file or when I removed the `classpathentry` lines from the `.classpath` file, the node 'Referenced Libraries (Read Only)' under `JAVA PROJECTS` in vscode view was removed. Why?

See the snapshots below for more details.

I appreciate your help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Since you have many libraries. I will strongly recommend you using maven or gradle. Even if you solve this issue now, it would not be compatible with other ide and with other team members.

Comment: I can't do that now since the project is for a Java Bean that has been deployed to production, and going through that path now is not an option, especially that I am not the owner of this project. I must fix the problem using the project I have.

Comment: Has your question been resolved? May i know if you ever reached my answer?

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT I can't thank you enough. You answer helped me a lot. I finally figured out how to solve my problem, but couldn't figure out the root-cause. That is fine... this is how it is in the field of computer science... that is there is no science what so ever... I will update the post very soon. Please bear with me!

Comment: @Hemang It appears that I have to convert the project to Maven. I need your help if you can. See the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69382705/how-to-convert-an-existing-eclipse-vscode-java-project-from-no-build-tools-used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @Molly Want-MSFT helped me a lot. Following is what I did to resolve the problem for good. I applied the steps below many time to verify they will work every time.

Steps to open a Java Project in both Eclipse and vscode:

1. Download the JDK needed for vscode, Eclipse and your Java Project.
2. Import the project in Eclipse and setup the JDK for the workspace and the project. Also, make sure to setup the compile level to match the JDK.
3. Set up the Project JDK to match the default of the workspace.
4. Build the project (Project-Cleanup) and Export the JAR to make sure all is OK.
5. Now open the project in vscode.
6. Setup `java.home` in Settings, in user and workspace sections. This must be JDK-11 or higher to allow vscode to function properly for Java Projects.
7. Add references to the installed JDKs in User's `settings.json` under `"java.configuration.runtimes"` section.
8. Restart vscode and take the option `Configure Java Runtime` from `JAVA PROJECTS` view. Make sure that the JDK of the Java Project is detected and working correctly.
9. You may have to open one of the Java Source Code Files. Wait a bit until it will settle down. Check the Java Build Status progress by clicking the spinning icon in the bottom right. This icon is for `Language Server` and it will turn into an icon that looks like thumbs-up when build/compile is done.
10. Close and open `Configure Java Runtime` to verify that the JDK was detected by vscode.
11. Ensure that both `JRE System Libraries` and `Referenced Libraries` under `JAVA PROJECTS` view are visible without any errors. Check the Problems view and try to resolve all errors.
12. The `Referenced Libraries` should be `Read Only` because this project was setup in Eclipse. You can delete the `.classpath` and `.project` files and open the project again in vscode, and try to fix the problems by adding libraries using the `+` button. When such files are deleted, the project will become `Unmanaged`. Later, you can restore such files.

When the project is `unmanaged`, you use `Configure Java Runtime` from `JAVA PROJECTS` view and you can check the project type. You can change the JDK to one of the installed ones as per the section `"java.configuration.runtimes"` in the user's `setting.json`.

13. If the the `Referenced Libraries` is read-only, it has no effect even if you can add libraries into settings.json, but the `.classpath` file will win.
14. From `JAVA PROJECTS` view, you can use the option `Build Workspace` and `Clean Workspace` to troubleshoot and try to resolve errors.
15. Finally, you can `Export JAR` from the option on `JAVA PROJECTS` view. This option is not clear and it looks like and arrow pointing to the right `|-->`.

I hope this helps, and if you have any question, please post a comment and I will try to answer back when possible.

Answer (score 3):

Basically speaking, java extension looks for jars from **Referenced Libraries**.

Here're my answers to your questions:

1. Right click the jar and choose `copy relative path` then add it to settings, click the refresh button then the added jar should be displayed under the option Referenced Libraries:
2. The **CLASSPATH** variable is one way to tell applications, including the JDK tools, where to look for user classes. When it comes to add jars, settings `java.project.referencedLibraries` wins.
3. No way to select
   jar folders but you can use keyboard shortcuts to select all jars then add them.
4. There's a setting called `"java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions"`, and it's true by default, so `.project` and `.classpath` won't be shown in VS Code.
5. The command **Java: Configure Classpath** works on my machine, which can customize current project.
   [image]
6. My guess is when you open a new project, vscode popped up a window and ask you if trust it, and you chose **Not**, then project is read-only. [Trusting the workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust#_trusting-a-workspace) then try the command **Java: Configure Classpath** again, it should be writeable.

Comment: Hi Molly, some additional information here:

- Adding folder is supported, for example, if you press alt on windows, you'll see the plus icon change to a folder button.

- The referenced libraries feature is only supported for the unmanaged folder project. if users see (Read-Only) on that node, then it's not available

Comment: @ShengChen. Got it. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I just change the path strings of the jars in the **.classpath** file and it works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).