# package ImportUtil does not exist

Tags: java, import, builder

I want to use this code snippet from here https://jackcess.sourceforge.io:

```
Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("my.mdb"));
new ImportUtil.Builder(db, "Imported").importResultSet(resultSet);
db.close();
```

like this:

```
import java.io.File;
// import java.util.Builder;
public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("blank.mdb"));
        new ImportUtil.Builder(db, "Imported2").setDelimiter(",").importFile(new File("testDf.csv"));
        db.close();
    }
  }
```

I am new to java so not so sure about how to import libraries. Currently, I get an error that:

```
java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("blank.mdb"));
    symbol:   variable DatabaseBuilder
    location: class ReadFile

java:10: error: package ImportUtil does not exist
    new ImportUtil.Builder(db, "Imported2").setDelimiter(",").importFile(new File("testDf.csv"));
```

I also tried `import java.util.Builder;`but i would still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the **ImportUtil from jackcess** is on your classpath.
There are tons of Tutorials on how to add a library to your project out there.

In case you use f.e. Maven just import this into your pom.xml file as a dependency.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.healthmarketscience.jackcess</groupId>
<artifactId>jackcess</artifactId>
<version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise please provide more details which ide you use and how you want to build your application.

Comment: I just have a single ```file.java```that I am using in VSCode. No separate pom.xml file for now

Comment: Here is how java dependencies are managed in VS Code.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_dependency-management

Comment: this is quite confusing, especially because idont see all the things displayed in the tutorial. What if I am not using any IDE? Is it possible to manually create a class path file? how would that look like? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54535301/12304000