# Java code not inserting data into MySQL database despite no errors

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I am facing a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` error with the message `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` when attempting to run my Java code for data insertion into a MySQL database. Surprisingly, the code compiles and runs without any errors, but the data is not being inserted into the database. Here's an overview of the issue:

- I'm using Java and JDBC to connect to a MySQL database and insert data into a table.
- I have made sure to include the MySQL JDBC driver JAR file in my project's classpath.
- When I run the code, I encounter the mentioned ClassNotFoundException error for the `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` class.
- However, if I only compile the code without running it, there are no errors.
- Despite the successful compilation, the data is not getting inserted into the database.

### **Here's a snippet of the code where I connect the JDBC:**

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Conn {
    /*
     * JDBC Connection has 4 Stages
     *  (1)-Register the Driver Class
     *  (2)-Creating Connection String
     *  (3)-Creating Statement
     *  (4)-Executing MySQL Queries
     *  (5)-Closing the Connection
     */

    Connection c; //reference variable
    Statement s; //
    Conn(){

        try{
            // (1)-Register the Driver Class
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            //Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
            // (2)-Creating Connection String
            /*
             * Connection String provides the information in which database you have connect
             */
            c= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/universitymanagementsystem","root", "123456789");
            System.out.println("Connection Established");
            // (3)
            s= c.createStatement();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /*public static java.beans.Statement createStatement() {
        return null;
    }*/
}
```

### **Here is the snippet of the code of AddStudent.java file**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
//import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;

public class AddStudent extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JTextField tfname, tffname, tffaddress, tfphone, tfemail, tfX, tfXII, tfAdhar, tfdob;
    JLabel labelrollno;
    JComboBox<String> cbCourse, cbBranch;
    JButton btnSubmit, btnCancel;
    // JDateChooser dobChooser;
    /*
     * create a object for random class
     * which create some random number for roll number
     */

    Random ran = new Random();
    long first4 = Math.abs((ran.nextLong() % 9000L) + 1000L);

    AddStudent() {

        // for layout
        setSize(900, 700);
        setLocation(350, 50);
        setLayout(null); // cause we want our own layout

        // for heading
        JLabel heading = new JLabel("New student Details");
        heading.setBounds(310, 30, 500, 50);
        heading.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
        add(heading);

        // name label
        JLabel labelName = new JLabel("Name");
        labelName.setBounds(50, 150, 100, 30);
        labelName.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(labelName);
        // name input box
        tfname = new JTextField();
        tfname.setBounds(200, 150, 150, 30);
        add(tfname);

        // father name label
        JLabel labelFName = new JLabel("Fathers Name");
        labelFName.setBounds(400, 150, 200, 30);
        labelFName.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(labelFName);
        // father name input box
        tffname = new JTextField();
        tffname.setBounds(600, 150, 150, 30);
        add(tffname);

        // roll name label
        JLabel lblRollNo = new JLabel("Roll Number");
        lblRollNo.setBounds(50, 200, 200, 30);
        lblRollNo.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(lblRollNo);
        setVisible(true);

        // roll nameinput box
        labelrollno = new JLabel("1533" + first4);
        labelrollno.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 30);
        labelrollno.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(labelrollno);
        setVisible(true);

        // date of birth
        JLabel lblDob = new JLabel("Date of Birth");
        lblDob.setBounds(400, 200, 200, 30);
        lblDob.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(lblDob);

        // date of birth input box
        tfdob = new JTextField();
        tfdob.setBounds(600, 200, 150, 30);
        add(tfdob);

        // date of birth input box
        /*
         * dobChooser = new JDateChooser();
         * dobChooser.setBounds(600, 200, 150, 30);
         * add(dobChooser);
         */

        // address label
        JLabel labeladdress = new JLabel("Address Name");
        labeladdress.setBounds(50, 250, 200, 30);
        labeladdress.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(labeladdress);
        // address name input box
        tffaddress = new JTextField();
        tffaddress.setBounds(200, 250, 150, 30);
        add(tffaddress);

        // phone number label
        JLabel labelPhone = new JLabel("Phone Number");
        labelPhone.setBounds(400, 250, 200, 30);
        labelPhone.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(labelPhone);
        // phone number input box
        tfphone = new JTextField();
        tfphone.setBounds(600, 250, 150, 30);
        add(tfphone);

        // Email Id
        JLabel labelemail = new JLabel("Email Id");
        labelemail.setBounds(50, 300, 200, 30);
        labelemail.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(labelemail);
        // Email Id input box
        tfemail = new JTextField();
        tfemail.setBounds(200, 300, 150, 30);
        add(tfemail);

        // Class X label
        JLabel labelX = new JLabel("Class X(%)");
        labelX.setBounds(400, 300, 200, 30);
        labelX.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(labelX);
        // Class X input box
        tfX = new JTextField();
        tfX.setBounds(600, 300, 150, 30);
        add(tfX);

        // Class XII label
        JLabel labelXII = new JLabel("Class XII(%)");
        labelXII.setBounds(50, 350, 200, 30);
        labelXII.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(labelXII);
        // Class XII input box
        tfXII = new JTextField();
        tfXII.setBounds(200, 350, 150, 30);
        add(tfXII);

        // Adhar Number label
        JLabel labelAdhar = new JLabel("Adhar Number");
        labelAdhar.setBounds(400, 350, 200, 30);
        labelAdhar.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(labelAdhar);
        // Adhar Number input box
        tfAdhar = new JTextField();
        tfAdhar.setBounds(600, 350, 150, 30);
        add(tfAdhar);

        // dropdown for course
        /*
         * JLabel labelCourse = new JLabel("Course");
         * labelCourse.setBounds(50, 400, 200, 30);
         * labelCourse.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
         * add(labelCourse);
         * String course[] = { "B.Tech", "M.Tech", "BBA", "MBA", "BCA", "MCA" };
         * cbCourse = new JComboBox(course);
         * cbCourse.setBounds(200, 400, 150, 30);
         * cbCourse.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
         * add(cbCourse);
         */

        // dropdown for course
        JLabel labelCourse = new JLabel("Course");
        labelCourse.setBounds(50, 400, 200, 30);
        labelCourse.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(labelCourse);

        String course[] = { "B.Tech", "M.Tech", "BBA", "MBA", "BCA", "MCA" };
        cbCourse = new JComboBox<>(course);
        cbCourse.setBounds(200, 400, 150, 30);
        cbCourse.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(cbCourse);

        // dropdown for branch
        JLabel labelBranch = new JLabel("Branch");
        labelBranch.setBounds(400, 400, 200, 30);
        labelBranch.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        add(labelBranch);

        String[] branch = { "CSE", "ECE", "EEE", "ME", "CE", "IT", "Not Applicable" };
        cbBranch = new JComboBox<>(branch);
        cbBranch.setBounds(600, 400, 150, 30);
        cbBranch.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        add(cbBranch);

        // submit button
        btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        btnSubmit.setBounds(200, 450, 150, 30);
        btnSubmit.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnSubmit.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(this);
        add(btnSubmit);

        // cancel button
        btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.setBounds(400, 450, 150, 30);
        btnCancel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnCancel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnCancel.addActionListener(this);
        add(btnCancel);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == btnSubmit) {
            // taking all the values
            String fname = tfname.getText();
            String ffname = tffname.getText();
            String rollno = labelrollno.getText();
            String dob = tfdob.getText();
            String address = tffaddress.getText();
            String phone = tfphone.getText();
            String email = tfemail.getText();
            String class_x = tfX.getText();
            String class_xii = tfXII.getText();
            String adhar = tfAdhar.getText();
            String course = (String) cbCourse.getSelectedItem();
            String branch = (String) cbBranch.getSelectedItem();

            // inserting into database

            try {
                String query = "insert into student values('"+fname+"', '"+ffname+"', '"+rollno+"', '"+dob+"', '"+address+"', '"+phone+"', '"+email+"', '"+class_x+"', '"+class_xii+"', '"+adhar+"', '"+course+"', '"+branch+"')";

                Conn con = new Conn();
                con.s.executeUpdate(query);
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student Details Inserted Successfully");
                setVisible(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    
        } else {
            setVisible(false);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AddStudent();
    }
}
```

Here is the proof that I already include the mysql-Connector jar file
[image]

### **Error and excception while I run the code**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)     
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)  
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
        at Conn.<init>(Conn.java:19)
        at AddStudent.actionPerformed(AddStudent.java:225)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)       
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)   
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Statement.executeUpdate(String)" because "<local15>.s" is null
        at AddStudent.actionPerformed(AddStudent.java:226)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

### **But when I hit Run Java that time no problem but the data is not inserted into database**

[image]

### **Data is not insert image**

[image]

I have been working on a Java code snippet to insert data into a MySQL database table, but I'm encountering unexpected behavior. Here's a summary of what I've tried and the expected outcome:

I have established a JDBC connection to the MySQL database using the appropriate connection parameters (URL, username, and password).
After successfully establishing the connection, I attempted to insert data into the table using an SQL insert statement.
However, despite running the code without any errors, the data is not being stored in the database table as expected.

I was expecting the code to insert the provided data into the specified table, but it seems to complete without any errors, yet the data is not being stored. I have verified that the connection parameters and SQL query are correct.

Any guidance or suggestions regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Make sure the mysql driver jar file is available to in your "referenced libraries" - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232557/visual-studio-code-java-extension-how-to-add-a-jar-to-classpath)

Comment: If you're using [tag:mysql], why did you also tag [tag:mssql-jdbc] which is for the JDBC driver of Microsoft SQL Server, an entirely different DBMS?

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct tables? you query is `insert into student` and table in screenshot which you included is named studentDetails

Comment: Wait, what? Title: "*despite no errors*" but in very first sentence: "*`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` error with the message `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` when attempting to run*", on next sentence "*runs without any errors*", later on "***Error and excception while I run the code***" with stack trace ??!!

Comment: I'm glad to inform you that I have resolved the issue I was facing with my Java code for data insertion into a MySQL database. It turns out that the problem was due to a mistake in specifying the table name.

Comment: I'm still experiencing the java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error with the message "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" when running my Java code using the VS Code Code Runner extension. Despite resolving the issue related to the incorrect table name, the driver class error persists. 

The code compiles and runs without any issues when executed through the regular "Run Java" command.
However, when I try to run the code using the Code Runner extension, I encounter the ClassNotFoundException for the com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver class.

Comment: Are you using the correct classpath?

Comment: You [don't need](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jdbc-loading-drivers) `Class.forName` unless you have a dated version of your driver. Strangely (I think) that's not the right class name anyway. Also [avoid null layouts](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing)

Comment: @g00se Since MySQL Connector/J 8, `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` is the correct class name (it still supports loading `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` for backwards compatibility).

Comment: My memory could be playing tricks here, but I seem to remember having had errors trying to load that class (unnecessarily like the OP) despite it being present and I *had* to load `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Update: with connector-j 8.0.29 ... *Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.* So it does work. Curiously, loading `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` produces no message telling you it's unnecessary ;)

Comment: @g00se The warning means that loading or using `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is deprecated (it is a subclass of `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` and the parent doesn't produce that warning); in addition it explains that manual loading is usually not necessary, because most code using `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` is likely cargo-culting it, so telling them they don't need to is a good thing. However, the SPI loader (ServiceLoader) **also** uses `Class.forName`, so writing a warning then is a bad idea and could lead to confusion.

Comment: The service definition file for MySQL Connector/J 8 references com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver, which is why that class doesn't trigger the warning.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have add the mysql Driver jar. Since you use reflection to load class Driver, it won't prompt errors when compiling.Only when the code is running to the process of loading class Driver, errors merge.