# Java JDK is different in VSCode than in the terminal

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I looked through a few questions similar to this but mine is too specific for them to help. For one of my classes at school, I need to run Hadoop mapreduce code.

I have fully configured my Hadoop and have it working in my terminal (which I am SSHed into) but the JDK of my VSCode (which is also connected via SSH) doesn't recognize that Hadoop exists (likely because they are not looking at the same JDK).

I am getting hundreds of errors when trying to import things and define classes in my code but it can compile fine because the terminal recognized Hadoop. It's mostly annoying because I want to see where the legitimate errors are.

[image: Hadoop Errors]

[image: Compilation working]

I am still getting an error because I have not completed the assignment but at least Hadoop is recognized by the compiler.

[image: Attempt to locate terminal JDK]

In the above image, you can see that I tried to change the JDK path to one of the ones provided to me in the terminal but it says there's nothing there. I have also tried to go the command to "Install New JDK" to see if it would let me use an existing one but it does not. This is all on SSH which is why I am having so much trouble. If I left anything out, please let me know and I will add it in.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: did you try to add the haddop jar extenally?are you using maven/gradel

Comment: @satyesht when we started this class they had us configure our bashrc file to import the resources for this class

`source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh`
`module purge`
`module load courses/cs435/pa0`
`source ~/.bashrc `

which allows the terminal to recognize what hadoop is. I'm not sure how to get that same functionality onto VSCode though. We never personally installed Hadoop onto our nodes

Comment: some where on your machine you will have hadoop-common.jar , search for this . in linux you can use find command and then add all jar in the project from that location

Comment: I'm not sure what you're being taught, but in practice, people don't use `hadoop  ... javac` command. They do use Maven/Gradle/sbt to package and distribute their code into jar files, not just `.class` files, regardless, that's unrelated to the IDE syntax highlighting or your Java path/version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS code, seems like your Hadoop jars are not part of your class path, hence VS Code is not able to recognize the import.
If you are not using Maven/Gradle, you may have to import them manually as below.

Please refer to this question on how to add external JAR files in VS Code:

> [Visual Studio Code, Java Extension, how to add a JAR to classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232557/visual-studio-code-java-extension-how-to-add-a-jar-to-classpath)

Comment: Okay thank you. I will try adding the jar to my VSCode manually!