# can't import com.jogamp in visual studio code

Tags: java, jogl

I can't import this in java project in visual studio code

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.gl2.GLUT;

import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL.GL_POINTS;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL2ES1.GL_POINT_SMOOTH;
```

I have no idea how to do this the tutorial on their page is so old and it doesn't have vs code there

Comment: You just have to add jogamp-fat.jar into the classpath: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54535301/458157